# Brightcove video freezes in Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, fancybox, brightcove

I've been experiencing issues with multiple Brightcove videos freezing at :19 seconds when played through Fancybox. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/qrqwy0qt/1/

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click the 'Play Video in Fancybox' button
2. Watch the video play through correctly
3. Refresh the page, or click 'Run' in jsfiddle
4. Play the video again in Fancybox, watch it freeze at :19 seconds.
5. Wait about a minute and the video shows "Could not download the video. Error code: PLAYER_ERR_TIMEOUT" and the following error is shown in the console:

   ```
   VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:-2 undefined)  i {code: -2, type: "PLAYER_ERR_TIMEOUT", message: ""}
   h @ index.html?videoId=5002405584001&autoplay=1:1300

   g.error @ index.html?videoId=5002405584001&autoplay=1:1300

   b @ index.html?videoId=5002405584001&autoplay=1:1307

   db @ index.html?videoId=5002405584001&autoplay=1:1297

   (anonymous function) @ index.html?videoId=5002405584001&autoplay=1:1308
   ```

This doesn't appear to happen when the video is embedded on the page normally, which you can also see in the jsfiddle.

Additionally, with certain video players you can even see the issue forming in the buffer progress bar:

[Video Progress Bar Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hs2IN.png)

You can see the color change on the progress bar right at :19 seconds. The video seems to have issues loading content after this point unless you manually seek beyond that point.

I've also had this issue using other lightboxes such as Brightcove's modal. Can anyone help me find a fix for this?

**Update:**

It seems the issue only occurs when the video height is over 270px, excluding the "letter-box" of the video player. You can test this with the following CSS properties:

```
.fancybox-inner{
    max-height:270px; // No freezing issue
    //min-height:275px; // Results in freezing
}
```

This isn't really a permanent solution because it prevents responsiveness on larger resolutions, but hopefully this information can bring us closer to a real solution.

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify the browser? I tested it on Firefox and Chrome and works fine.

Comment: I've tested on multiple browsers, operating systems, and networks. I've encountered the error on the following setups:

**Mac OSX:**
Chrome 49 & Firefox 45,

**Ubuntu 14.04:**
Chromium 48 & Firefox 44,

**Windows 7:**
Chrome 49

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't reproduce the error. I know that BrightCove have different codification and get back to the final user. It's depend also to user connection. What you can try is to retranscode the video from BC console.